# How to receive text from <div> tag?

Tags: php, html, preg-match, title

I have a tag `<div class="text9">` with text. I need to add this text in the title. For example: `<div> for sale`. How can I do that?

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
preg_match('#<div class="text9">(.*?)</div>#isU'$text, $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it's value by simply doing:

```
var out = $('.text9').text();
alert(out);
```

hope that helps

EDIT: In order to pass the variable to php you'll have to use AJAX as follows:

```
var out= $('.text9').text();
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {x: out},
    type: 'POST'
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['x']; ?>
```

Comment: I tried to use it and I had empty page
<?
var out = $('.text9').text();
alert(out);
 ?>

Comment: Are you trying to fetch it into a php variable?

Comment: You can't do it directly, you must use AJAX.